# I need to convert a string date to an actual date

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012-express

I have a Date field in a table that is an int.  The value looks like this:  20130618  I want to be able to convert that to an actual date like 06/18/2013 so I can do date calculations on it.  How do I convert that field?

Comment: Change the table. Or what do you expect to do when you encounter a value like `20130299`? The design is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select convert(date, left(20130618, 8), 101)
```

or

```
select convert(date, cast(20130618 as char(8)), 101)
```

Comment: Sorry, the field is actually an integer.

Comment: Have altered my answer to operate on integers instead